# how to apply pyannote.audio model on my data without getting "killed"?

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, pytorch

following the tutorial [Applying pretrained models on your own data](https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio/tree/develop/tutorials/pretrained/model) gets my process killed when applying the model. RAM is not used fully, but cores go up to 100% and then go back to 0 in a few seconds.

Here's my code (the audio is 2 min, .wav):

```
import torch
import multiprocessing 

torch.set_num_threads(multiprocessing.cpu_count())

print('downloading model')
sad = torch.hub.load('pyannote/pyannote-audio', 'sad_ami', device='cpu', batch_size=32)
print('finished')

test_file = {'uri': 'audio_real.wav', 'audio': './audio.wav'}

print('applying sad')
sad_scores = sad(test_file)
print('finished')

print('binarizing')
from pyannote.audio.utils.signal import Binarize
binarize = Binarize(offset=0.52, onset=0.52, log_scale=True, 
                    min_duration_off=0.1, min_duration_on=0.1)
print('finished')

print('applying')
speech = binarize.apply(sad_scores, dimension=1)
print('finished')

print(speech)
```

If I apply it on audios with 5 sec it works perfectly. I've also ran that on a GCP machine with 64 cores and 64 GB of RAM, and I still got the process killed, with the last message being 'applying sad', and then "Killed".

Comment: Where are you running the code?

Comment: On a jupyter notebook in GCP.

Comment: But you said "also run on GCP." Are you saying you got the same issue with physical machine and GCP VM?